# Find Element by Title using javascript with Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, title

I'm adding javascript method in sharepoint where I need to get elements by title and Id and Names are changeing. I'm not sure of the syntax for writing such a method and I can't find good examples of doing so. 
Please help.
My code looks like this for now.

```
 function ValidateComments()
 {
 var val1 = elements[index].title("inspection");
 var val2 = elements[index].title("Start date");
 var val3 = elements[index].title("End date");
 var val4 = elements[index].title("Comments");

  if (val1 === true){

  if ((val2 !== "" && val3 !== "") || val4 !="")

   }
   alert("Valid");

    }
   else {

    alert("NOT Valid");

     }
```

Comment: It is not possible to use the getElementById(); OR getElementByName(); as both Id and Name and change most of the time.

Comment: Can you add relevant HTML, so that we can see the structure of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below code :

```
var val1 = document.querySelector('[title="inspection"]').value;
```

**Note: It returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors, or null if no matches are found.**

Refer below Output:
[image]